# How to decode g703 raw audio data 64kbs 8000 hz

Tags: audio, audio-streaming, codec

I have a chunk of data encoded in g703.

I have read the g703 wiki page and googled a lot but I cannot find a good/simple explanation of how I can convert this raw data in wav format using Sox or other tools

Do you any suggestion on how I can convert this data?

It seems that the g703 is not a proper codec but only a particular standard for pcm. 
How should manipulate my data in order to play it?

Comment: I think G.703 is an electrical standard, i.e. how to represent a digital stream on a cable.  If you have a file, it's probably encoded in G.711 mu-law.  Try `sox -e mu-law -r 8000 -b input.raw output.wav`.

Comment: sox FAIL sox: Bits value `input.raw' is not a positive integer

Comment: I have tried u-law a-law and mu-law with rate at 8000. Only noise

Comment: Sorry, `-b` was a typo.  But I take it you got sox running, with no good output.  Maybe show us the hexdump of 32 bytes or so to see if the format jumps out?

Comment: C0 0C 00 03 00 00 37 C0 34 0C D0 30 37 C0 30 C7 CD D3 C0 03 CD 00 37 03 C0 00 0D 0C CD 00 C0 10 0F 00 03 55 0B 4B 0F 0F 0C 0F 34 0F 0D C3 0D 03 00 C0 31 00 00 D0 C0 00 F4 4C 03 33 34 33 31 33 0D 33 D0 03 C0 4C C0 43 F7 4C 03 57 32 08 03 32 C0 3F 31 3F 0D 33 0C 00 00 00 0D 00 30 34 30 55 32 DB CC 03 F3 D3 F0 C0 00 0C 00 00 D0 00 0C D0 00 43 03 03 30 34 03 CD 4C C3 DC 30 C7 CC C4 F0 34 F0 0D 0C DC 30

Comment: Please keep in mind that I am not sure about the format of this raw data. I suppose it to be any among: u-law mu-law g729 g726 pcm adpcm etc. Thanks

Comment: @QuentinTanioartino if you could post your file online we could see if our/any  code can parse it

Comment: Did you try adpcm, e.g. `sox -e ima-adpcm -r 8000 input.raw output.wav`?  It looks like encoding in 4-bit nybbles to me.

Comment: sox FAIL formats: bad input format for file `input.raw': data encoding or sample size was not specified

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bgqu92vkyt7p203/input.raw